# Python markdown automatically link URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, markdown, markup

I want to automatically link URLs if typed in
text, I am unable to find an extension for it and
not really sure how I'd do it myself,

For example this is NOT what I want, but it's the default
behaviour

```py
>>> import markdown
>>> markdown.markdown("https://google.com/")
'<p>https://google.com/</p>'
```

But I want it to be

```py
>>> import markdown
>>> markdown.markdown("https://google.com/")
'<a href="https://google.com/">https://google.com/</a>'
```

Any extension to do that or should I go for regex or....

Thanks for the answers in advance

Comment: Don't you want something more like `markdown.markdown("[Google](https://google.com/)")`?

Comment: @JonSG it's too much to type and very very repedative, the reason I am doing this is that I have a blog generator that uses markdown and it gets very annoying when linking sources or something to type [source one](https.....) and so on

Comment: In the list of Third Party Extensions for Python-Markdown, there is a whole section on [URL Conversion](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/wiki/Third-Party-Extensions#url-conversion). Do those not meet your needs?

Comment: This did https://github.com/daGrevis/mdx_linkify thanks @Waylan (d)

Comment: Also, why not just use [Automatic Links](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autolink) (wrap the link in angle brackets)? Like this: `<https://example.com>`.

Comment: @Waylan Wow, did not know this was a thing, though I think I still prefer mdx_linkify, no need to type anything besides the url :)

Comment: @Waylan `<https://example.com>` does not work in Python Markdown. It passes through the entire angle-bracketed text verbatim, which makes it an invisible "tag".

Comment: @LutzPrechelt that's not what I get. `markdown.markdown('<https://example.com>')` returns `'<p><a href="https://example.com">https://example.com</a></p>'` as expected.